# Why isn't this simple JavaScript function working as I expect? Trying to determine if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, client-side

I have HTML in the following form:

```
<div id="filters">
    <ul>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".one">One</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".two">Two</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".three">Three</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".four">Four</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".five">Five</label></li>
        <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" checked data-filter=".six">Six</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript function is as follows:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function initFilters()
{
    $('#filters input').each(function(){
        if ($(this).checked) {
            console.log($(this).attr('data-filter')+' is checked');
            addFilter($(this).attr('data-filter'));
        } else {
            console.log($(this).attr('data-filter')+' is unchecked');
            removeFilter($(this).attr('data-filter'));
        };
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `$(this).checked` always returns false.

Comment: learn to use browser console, first alert would be this error `$(this).checked is not a function` or similar error text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checked` is a property of the DOM element, not of a jQuery object.

```
if (this.checked) {
```

---

You can also retrieve said property with the [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) jQuery object method:

```
if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
```

However the snippet above creates a new jQuery object and calls a method on it, which is not recommended - it is unnecessary, provides slower performance and takes more typing. I do also find the native method easier to read.

`.prop` is more appropriate when working with a set of elements or passing a selector instead of a DOM element reference.

Though, choose whichever you find more readable and maintainable, as both work just fine for your use case.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property. Try this:

```
this.checked
```

or

```
$(this).prop("checked")
```

I find the first way easier to read, and it is certainly more efficient, but some people insist on using jQuery for *everything,* so...